# getting error while trying to extract month from date

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to extract month from input date. I am trying this

```
select
    case
        when extract(month from :myDate) <= 6 then '1st' 
        when extract(month from :myDate) >= 7 then '2nd'
    end as half_of_the_year
from dual
```

If i enter `2-12-12` then i get the error that

```
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source
30076. 00000 -  "invalid extract field for extract source"
*Cause:    The extract source does not contain the specified extract field.
*Action:
```

Why i am getting this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to explicitly convert your bind variable to the date datatype using `to_date` function:

```
select
    case
        when extract(month from to_date(:mydate, 'dd-mm-rr')) <= 6 then '1st'
        when extract(month from to_date(:mydate, 'dd-mm-rr')) >= 7 then '2nd'
    end as half_of_the_year
from dual
```